# OpenCV Extract open edges from image after using Canny algorithm

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

I'm trying to extract the edge of a drop from the following image which I've first applied `cv2.Canny()` onto:

[image: Image of drop]

I tried using `cv2.findContours()` (and taking the longest contour found) but this ends up being a closed loop around the drop's 1 pixel edge (shown exaggerated in blue).

Is there a way to extract just a single open edge (as a list of (x, y) points, similar to the structure of a contour returned by `findContours()`) that goes around the profile of the drop?

---

**Images:**

[Original Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ORlJr.png)

[After applying Canny](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KrxR4.png)

Comment: can you please post the original image?

Comment: @janu777 I've made an edit.